# Populate existing array/table with new data

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach

I'm still at the beginning of learning powershell. My goal here is to have a script that pulls SCOM alerts that are one day old, compares the alerts' netbios computer name to a value from a CSV that I will import.

If the ServerName from the CSV Matches the NetbiosName it then adds the Administrator Name to the original Array/Table I created. Currently it does everything I ask of it, but when I have it output the final data it only has the last administrator that was used added to the Admin column instead of the appropriate admin.

> NetbiosComputerName         : Server
>
> MonitoringObjectDisplayName : Server.Domain
>
> Name                        : Blah Blah Blah
>
> Severity                    : Warning
>
> ResolutionState             : 0
>
> RepeatCount                 : 0
>
> Server Adminstrator         : Admin
>
> ---
>
> NetbiosComputerName         : Server
>
> MonitoringObjectDisplayName : Server.Domain
>
> Name                        : Blah Blah Blah
>
> Severity                    : Warning
>
> ResolutionState             : 0
>
> RepeatCount                 : 0
>
> Server Adminstrator         : Admin

On the Second output the Admin should instead reflect the admin for that particular server and not very same one.

Here is my code.

```
     # Load SCOM snap-in
add-pssnapin "Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.OperationsManager.Client";
$server = "RMSSERVER"

# Connect to OpsMgr SDK - change management server to your RMS
new-managementGroupConnection -ConnectionString:RMSSERVER.domain;
set-location "OperationsManagerMonitoring::";

$Date = (Get-Date).adddays(-1)

$ScomAlert = get-alert | where {($_.ResolutionState -eq 0) -and ($_.TimeRaised -gt $Date)  } | Select NetbiosComputerName,MonitoringObjectDisplayName, Name,Severity, ResolutionState, RepeatCount
$Administrators = Import-CSV "C:\Script\SCOM\admin.csv"
$TableSC = $ScomAlert



ForEach ($Alert in $ScomAlert)
{
    $NetBios       = "$($Alert.NetBiosComputerName)"
    $MonObjectName = "$($Alert.MonitoringObjectDisplayName)"
    $AlertName     = "$($Alert.Name)"
    $Severity      = "$($Alert.Severity)"
    $ResState      = "$($Alert.ResolutionState)"
    $RepCount      = "$($Alert.RepeatCount)"
   

        ForEach ( $Admin in $Administrators ) 
       {
            $ServerName  = "$($Admin.ServerName)"
            $ServerAdmin = "$($Admin.AdminName)"
           
            if($ServerName -eq $NetBios)
            {
               $ServerAdministrator = $ServerAdmin    
               
            } 
         
       }
    
     $TableSC | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server Adminstrator" -Value $ServerAdministrator -Force
  
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$TableSC | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server Adminstrator" ...
```

The above line replaces the property `Server Administrator` in **all** items of the collection `$TableSC` with the given value.

If you want each item updated with the respective administrator you need something like this (untested):

```
$Administrators = @{}
Import-Csv "C:\Script\SCOM\admin.csv" | % {
  $Administrators[$_.ServerName] = $_.AdminName
}

$TableSC = $ScomAlert | select NetBiosComputerName,
  MonitoringObjectDisplayName, Name, Severity, ResolutionState, RepeatCount,
  @{n="Server Administrator";e={$Administrators[$_.NetBiosComputerName]}}
```

Comment: Thank You, that absolutely did what I wanted and looked for. Much simpler than what I was working towards too.